# [MySQL]0 records imported when using Table Data Import Wizard JSON file in MySQL Workbench 8.0

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using **MySQL Workbench 8.0**.

My JSON file contains **100 records** data with **6 columns** and it is **utf8**.

My table is **utf8bm4** and it had 1 foreign key.

When I use **Table Data Import Wizard** of Workbench to import my JSON file. All columns are matched, but when it completely imported, **the message log** show off

[image]

And **the output logs**

[image]

I **tried to split the JSON** in smaller parts (each part contained 10 records) but the result was same.

I have tried to import in another table of my database and everything was ok! But those files had only 1 column.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try Export as "SQL INSERT Statements" and run queries on workbench.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. No error message or anything. Looks like this wizard is not well tested.

Comment: @Jitendra how is that supposed to work, did you really read OP's message?